# SQL INDEX when using LIKE operator (DB2)

Tags: sql, indexing, db2

I know that in Oracle there is such thing called DOMAIN INDEX. How but in DB2?

I have statement in my large table:

```
SELECT * from TABLE where (upper(COLUMN1) like '%HGW%'))
```

Regular normal INDEX on COLUMN1 will not be helpful because of UPPER and LIKE.
What is the syntax to create some powerful index which will have effect on this UPPER and LIKE statements to get fast result of this query?
I will appreciate example and help.
Unfortunately I can't delete nethier first % or second %.

Comment: You might want to check out the DB2 index extensions (analogue to the Oracle DOMAIN INDEX, which belongs to the Oracle index extensions) at: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0805stolze2/

Comment: Hi, sorry but I cant find there nothing similar to this. Maybe I missed something. on what section did you think I should take attention?

Answer (score 1):

First thing, whenever you run a function like `upper` or `lower` on the column, the index on that column won't be utilized and the RDBMS will resort to a full table scan. For the index to work, the column should be left alone. Even:

```
SELECT col1 from table where col2+1 = 3
```

won't work, because you are running a function (addition) on the column, so the index (if any) on `col2` won't be utilized. Hence you have to change it to:

```
SELECT col1 from table where col2 = 3-1
```

2nd thing, when the pattern begins with a wildcard, like `*` or `.`, the index won't be utilized either, because, as you can easily guess, the RDBMS will have no way of knowing which character the column value is starting with. So there are two steps:

First, change you collation so that `foo` matches both `Foo` as well as `fOo`. That way th `upper` is taken care of.

Second, you have to take care of the wildcard part. If there are indeed many characters allowed before `HG`, then your best bet would be to use a full-text index (dunno whether DB2 has one). This index is specially built for these purposes, full-text-search, so you can utilize that. Of course, it will consume more resources, because the index structure is pretty elaborate, but you have to live with that.

Comment: You can define an index that is used for `upper` queries: Just define an index on the *expression* that is used in the WHERE clause.

Comment: `create index idx_upper_bar on foo (upper(bar))` That index will be used for this where clause: `where upper(bar) = 'BLA'`

Comment: Hi thanks for help. So you think that for upper it will have effect? create index idx_upper_bar on TABLE (upper(COLUMN1)) is this what you thought? But in your query  where upper(bar) = 'BLA' there is not like operator?

Comment: will this index be useful in my query SELECT * from TABLE where (upper(COLUMN1) like '%HGW%'))

Comment: Your table still won't use the index because you have a wild card on the left side of your string there. (In fancy words, it's not [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)). What you're asking the database is like asking someone to find all the people in the phone book that have "hgw" anywhere in their name. You can take advantage of the index (the ordering by last name, in this example), because it can be any part of the name. They still have to go name-by-name one at a time to find this string.